# Group by dictionary value in for loop

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to group by dictionary value inside for loop in an django template.

My template is as follows :

```
<div id="engines-rows">
    {% for engine in engines %}
        <h3>{{ engine }}</h3>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Result that I get is as follows :

```
{'id': 8, 'name': '2.0 TFSI', 'fuel_type': 'PETROL', 'displacement_cc': 1984, 'power_hp': 188, 'power_ps': 190, 'power_kw': 140}
{'id': 7, 'name': '2.0 TDI', 'fuel_type': 'DIESEL', 'displacement_cc': 1968, 'power_hp': 181, 'power_ps': 184, 'power_kw': 135}
{'id': 6, 'name': '2.0 TDI', 'fuel_type': 'DIESEL', 'displacement_cc': 1968, 'power_hp': 148, 'power_ps': 150, 'power_kw': 110}
{'id': 5, 'name': '1.6 TDI', 'fuel_type': 'DIESEL', 'displacement_cc': 1598, 'power_hp': 109, 'power_ps': 110, 'power_kw': 81}
{'id': 4, 'name': '1.4 TFSI g-tron', 'fuel_type': 'CNG', 'displacement_cc': 1395, 'power_hp': 109, 'power_ps': 110, 'power_kw': 81}
{'id': 3, 'name': '1.4 TFSI e-tron', 'fuel_type': 'ELECTRICITY', 'displacement_cc': 1395, 'power_hp': 148, 'power_ps': 150, 'power_kw': 110}
{'id': 2, 'name': '1.4 TFSI', 'fuel_type': 'PETROL', 'displacement_cc': 1395, 'power_hp': 148, 'power_ps': 150, 'power_kw': 110}
{'id': 1, 'name': '1.0 TFSI', 'fuel_type': 'PETROL', 'displacement_cc': 999, 'power_hp': 114, 'power_ps': 116, 'power_kw': 85}
```

I want to group by fuel_type, thus I want to see something like :

**Petrol**

Name: 2.0 TFSI  --  displacement_cc: 1984  --  power_hp: 188  --  power_ps: 190  --  power_kw: 140
Name: 1.4 TFSI  --  displacement_cc: 1395  --  power_hp: 148  --  power_ps: 150  --  power_kw: 110
........

**Diesel**

Name: 2.0 TDI  --  displacement_cc: 1968  --  power_hp: 181  --  power_ps: 184  --  power_kw: 135
Name: 2.0 TDI  --  displacement_cc: 1968  --  power_hp: 148  --  power_ps: 150  --  power_kw: 110
....

............

I cant do it something like

```
<div id="engines-rows">
    {% for engine in engines %}
        {% if engine.fuel_type == "PETROL" %}
            # Do something
        {% endif %}
        {% if engine.fuel_type == "DIESEL" %}
            # Do something
        {% endif %}
         # And so on
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

But can I do it dynamically, I do not want to add if for every fuel type.

Thanks

Comment: group it before you send to template.

Comment: @furas How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not a django expert, but it seems to be close to what you need: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as follows :

```
<div id="engines-rows">
    {% regroup engines|dictsort:"fuel_type" by fuel_type as fuel_type_list %}
    {% for fuel_type in fuel_type_list %}
        <div style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
            <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;background-color: #263238; color: #ffffff;height: 40px;display: block;padding: 10px 15px;border: 1px solid #ddd;">{{ fuel_type.grouper }}</div>
            {% for engine in fuel_type.list %}
                <a id="engine-row" class="col-lg-12" style="margin-bottom: 5px;" data-engine-id={{ engine.id }}>
                    <div class="col-lg-3" data-engine-id={{ engine.id }}>{{ engine.name }}</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3" data-engine-id={{ engine.id }}>{{ engine.displacement_cc }} ccm</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3" data-engine-id={{ engine.id }}>{{ engine.power_ps }} pk</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3" data-engine-id={{ engine.id }}>{{ engine.power_kw }} kW</div>
                </a>
                <div class="clearfix" />
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The **YK Li's** solution gave my :

**Petrol**

Name: 2.0 TFSI -- displacement_cc: 1984 -- power_hp: 188 -- power_ps: 190 -- power_kw: 140

**Diesel**

Name: 2.0 TDI -- displacement_cc: 1984 -- power_hp: 188 -- power_ps: 190 -- power_kw: 140 
Name: 2.0 TDI -- displacement_cc: 1984 -- power_hp: 188 -- power_ps: 190 -- power_kw: 140 
Name: 1.6 TDI -- displacement_cc: 1984 -- power_hp: 188 -- power_ps: 190 -- power_kw: 140

**CNG**

Name: 1.4 TFSI g-tron -- displacement_cc: 1984 -- power_hp: 188 -- power_ps: 190 -- power_kw: 140

**ELECTRICITY**

Name: 1.4 TFSI e-tron -- displacement_cc: 1984 -- power_hp: 188 -- power_ps: 190 -- power_kw: 140

**Petrol**

Name: 1.4 TFSI -- displacement_cc: 1984 -- power_hp: 188 -- power_ps: 190 -- power_kw: 140 
Name: 1.0 TFSI -- displacement_cc: 1984 -- power_hp: 188 -- power_ps: 190 -- power_kw: 140

That was not what I wanted.

[In the docs (the link that Ilya V. Schurov posted)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) stays that the solution is to sort the data in the template using the dictsort filter, if your data is in a list of dictionaries:

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider preparing the data in your view.

```
from collections import defaultdict

grouped_engines = defaultdict(list)

for engine in engines:
    grouped_engines[engine['fuel_type']].append(engine)
```

Now your template can stay way simpler.

The basic structure would look like this:

```
{% for fuel_type, engines in grouped_engines.items %}
    {{ fuel_type }}
    {% for engine in engines %}
      {{ engine }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The `regroup` tag should work as well, but putting the logic in the view feels closer to Django's general attitude regarding templates and logic:

> [Data should be calculated in views, then passed to templates for display.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/language/#accessing-method-calls)

Comment: OP needs `'fuel_type'` instead of `'name'`

Answer (score 0):

Just post the sample as mentioned in comment from Ilya V. Schurov

```
<div id="engines-rows">
    {% regroup engines by fuel_type as fuel_list %}
    {% for fuel in fuel_list %}
        <h2>{{ fuel.grouper }}</h2>
        {% for engine in fuel.list %}
            <h3>{{ engine }}</h3>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```